# How do I indicate that a position was part-time on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-description, part-time

I am working on my resume, and the position that I have held for the past few years has been part-time (and remote). Do I need to indicate that somehow? If so, how? The headings for my employment sections looks something like this:

```
Software Engineer                               September 2012 - December 2014
*Company Name, Location*
```

Followed by bullet points indicating job responsibilities / projects worked on.

Comment: If you worked a fixed number of hours per week it may be helpful to include that: Software Engineer (10 hours per week).

Comment: How were you occupying the remainder of your time?

Comment: For any type of creative job (anything that doesn't require repetitive, mind numbing tasks) I would not. Experience is about things you learned, technologies you have used not how many hours you sit on your ass in front of the computer.

Answer (score 2):

The first question you need to ask yourself is: would disclosing this help you?  If your list of accomplishments in the position looks lean for the amount of time you were there, but that's because you only worked there half-time or less, then it's potentially worth indicating that it was a part-time job.  If your resume wouldn't raise eyebrows if you didn't say this, then don't.  Remember: the purpose of the *resume* is to get the interview; later on you will disclose your job history in much more detail (possibly including positions you omitted entirely from the resume), either verbally at the interview or via a written application.  If the company doesn't seem to be the sort that has formal written applications, then I suggest bringing it up in the interview so they won't later feel you've misrepresented yourself.

If you do include it on your resume, readers will naturally wonder "part-time? what else was he doing?".  So make sure your resume (or, if necessary, cover letter) has an explanation for that, or you might find people passing on your resume before they ever talk with you.  Job dates that overlap education dates are a pretty clear signal.

As for *how* to indicate it, "(part-time)" after the job title is the usual way in my experience (US, high-tech sector).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere the candidate shouldn't get to the offer without having been clear about this, but I don't think it needs to necessarily be right there on the resume.  If somebody had been working full-time except was out for several months due to a medical leave, resulting in the same number of hours worked as the part-timer, would you want that to be disclosed?  Also, some people in a role spend nearly 100% of their time the primary task while others spend <50%.  The resume should describe what the person did; the interview should drill into the details, because there's lots of variation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is any reason to specifically indicate that the job was part time.  If asked about your duties during a interview, it would be appropriate to state that the job was not full time, but be prepared to have a explanation for what you were doing with the rest of your time.

Comment: I completely disagree. It's very important to indicate that a particular job was part-time.

Comment: @WorkerDrone: Why is that important ?

Comment: @Sorin - because people who would hire you don't think part-time experience has the same value as full-time

Comment: @WorkerDrone, and why is that ?

Comment: @Sorin - because it doesn't have the same value.

Comment: It's not a axiom! Instead of trying to be a smart ass, maybe you should answer the question. Why doesn't it have the same value ?

Comment: @Sorin - I work for 3 months at 20 hours per week. You work for the same 3 months at 40 hours+ per week. Which has more value? Isn't this obvious?

Comment: @WorkerDrone, no it isn't. It depends on what you spend the hours, and what you learn there. Especially for jobs like software engineering, where you you don't stop working when you punch out or take a smoking break.

Comment: @Sorin - you don't see any difference between working part-time and working full-time. I do. I'd guess I'm in the majority on that. Anyway the question was "How do I indicate that a position was part-time", not "is it necessary". Thanks for chatting.

Comment: @WorkerDrone if I spent 40 hours a week for a year peeling potatoes, I don't know that I'd be that much more qualified than someone who did it for 20 hours a week for a year. Depends on the work and total length of time, not hours per week.

Comment: @mcknz - fair point about the potato peeler job. Although I believe the OP is actually a Software Engineer.

Comment: @WorkerDrone right. I agree there's a difference between part- and full-time work, but for the purposes of I resume, I would be mostly interested in the job title and the skills used, as opposed to full or part-time status (which sadly can sometimes be 39 hours a week).